Cambiar formato de datos de fecha y hora
Tengo un dataframe con los datos de comienzo de sueño y final en tipo tiemstamp en segundos y quiero cambiarlos a la fecha y hora que corresponden, os dejo una muestra. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Yo he probado con esto:
datetime.timedelta(seconds) 

Pero me devuelve algo como esto con la fecha mal:
30/12/1899 6:33:00

Data:
sleep_start            sleep_end

34200.0                -10620.0
24300.0                -0.0
21600.0                -8400.0
34555.0                3955.0
33046.0                -15553.0
37601.0                -16998.0

Saludos y gracias!
Xavier.

Hola Xavier, dudo que eso sea UNIX timestamp/Unix epoch sin más, porque las que muestras serian del 1 de Enero de 1970... sin tener en cuenta los negativos que en todo caso serían anteriores...Es más, si representara el inicio del sueño y el final del mismo en tiempos desde epoch (o desde x), ¿no debería ser siempre sleep_start < sleep_end?

ah pues yo lo había entendido como que después de las 00:00h sale en negativo por que le debes restar un día al haber pasado a partir de las 00:00, y que el que es positivo es dormir por el día tipo siesta.

datetime.timedelta(seconds) te devuelve un timedelta en dias, no en segundos. Además, algo más supongo que realizás, por que lo que me envía el interprete es un objeto timedelta, no una fecha. Para trabajar con segundos, deberías pasar el argumento seconds=seconds al timedelta. Leyendo tu otro comentario: timedelta representa un lapzo o diferencia de tiempo si vos pones que una persona se durmió a las 8 y despertó a la misma hora, la resta de los dos daría 0, excepto que agreges un día. No se el contexto, pero para hacer esto suele ser conveniente trabajar con el objeto datetime.

Gracias por la respuesta Dante, puedes poner un ejempo con datetime, no lo he entendido muy bien para llevarlo a la práctica.

Falta bastante contexto aquí. No puedes obtener una fecha si solo tienes una duración, necesitas un punto de partida, por ejemplo UNIX timestamp son segundos pasados desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Si estas generando la fecha sumándole el timedelta a una fecha de partida que tu tienes, solo ten en cuenta lo que comenta Dante, el primer argumento posicional de timedelta es días no segundos, deberías obtener tus fechas haciendo algo como fecha_inicio_sueño = fecha_de_referencia + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)  donde fecha_de_referencia es un objeto datetime.

Si, tenéis razón, ha sido un error mío al convertir los datos. Creo que ahora ya sé como hacaerlo. Muchas gracias!

Creo que lo que le falta a tu pregunta es cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener de estos datos de entrada. Digamos, cuál es la representación correcta de 34200.0? y la de -10620.0? y así, de cada uno de tus datos de ejemplo...
